# Getting a value from an ArrayList java

Tags: java

I am trying to get a value from with in an `ArrayList`. I have two classes, the main and a Car class. here is the code:

```
  public class CarOrders {
     public static void main (String [] args){
        Car toyota= new Car("Toyota", "$10000", "300"+ "2003");
        Car nissan= new Car("Nissan", "$22000", "300"+ "2011");
        Car ford= new Car("Ford", "$15000", "350"+ "2010");

        ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
        cars.add(toyota);        
        cars.add(nissan);
        cars.add(ford);
     }

public static void processCar(ArrayList<Car> cars){
       int totalAmount=0;
       for (int i=0; i<cars.size(); i++){
          cars.get(i).computeCars ();
         totalAmount+= ?? 
      // in need to add the computed values of totalprice from the Car class?

       }
      System.out.println (totalAmount);

    }


}    
class Car {
     public Car (String name, int price, int, tax, int year)
     {
       constructor.......
     }

     public void computeCars ()
     {
      int  totalprice= price+tax;
      System.out.println (name + "\t" +totalprice+"\t"+year );
     }

}
```

How would i be able to calculate `totalAmount` in the `processCar()` method where `totalAmount=totalAmount+totalPrice` from the `computCar()` method in the Car Class?

Comment: Make `computeCars()` return `totalprice`. Thus `totalAmount += cars.get(i).computeCars ()`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `return price+tax;` from `computeCars()` :

```
 public int computeCars ()
 {
  return price+tax;
 }
```

then :

```
    public static void processCar(ArrayList<Car> cars){
       int totalAmount=0;
       for (int i=0; i<cars.size(); i++){
         totalAmount+= cars.get(i).computeCars(); 
       }
      System.out.println (totalAmount);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you change the signature of your `computCar()` method

```
public int computeCar() { ... }
```

and return the `totalPrice` as value from this method call. Thus you can use it in your method `processCar()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int  computeCars ()
     {
      return price+tax;

     }


public static void processCar(ArrayList<Car> cars){
       int totalAmount=0;
       for (int i=0; i<cars.size(); i++){

         totalAmount=+ cars.get(i).computeCars ();
      // in need to add the computed values of totalprice from the Car class?

       }
      System.out.println (totalAmount);

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to make some changes in you Car class, it should be like this:

```
class Car {
 //i'm adding only 2 properties you can add all the properties
 public int price;
 public int tax;
 public Car (String name, int price, int tax, int year)
 {
   //here you should add these 2 lines
   this.price=price;
   this.tax=tax;
 }
```

and you function will be:

```
  public static void processCar(ArrayList<Car> cars){
   int totalAmount=0;
   for (int i=0; i<cars.size(); i++){
      cars.get(i).computeCars ();
     totalAmount=+ cars.get(i).price;
  // in need to add the computed values of totalprice from the Car class?

   }
  System.out.println (totalAmount);

}
```